# Can this way break cycle retain

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
_inputNickNameView = [[PWInputNickNameView alloc] initWithSubmitBlock:^{

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(facebookLoginWithDispalyName:)]) {
        [_delegate oginWithDispalyName:_inputNickNameView.displayName];
    }

    [_inputNickNameView release];
    _inputNickNameView = nil;
}];
```

Hello, any one know that writes like this can break cycle retain in the _inputNickName instance under non-arc or not?

Comment: Are you not using ARC?

Comment: The block retains `self`, not `_inputNickNameView` instance.

Comment: 1. The code doesn't compile. 2. Use identifiers without spelling mistakes. 3. Use ARC. 4. If you don't use ARC which is stupid in 2015, use properties. 5. Turn warnings on in the compiler.